# What is a unmatched match in regex?

Tags: c++

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/str:

> if `n >= size()`, a string representing the unmatched match is returned.

What is this *unmatched match*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The call is equivalent to `string_type((*this)[n]);`

and [operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at) gives more info:

> if `n >= size()`, returns a reference to a `std::sub_match` representing an unmatched sub-expression **(an empty subrange of the target sequence)**.

Comment: I still don't get it. Could you give me a example? Because every time I tried to use `n` >= `size()`, I got nothing returned.

Comment: -> empty subrange. So instead of having out of bound access as you might have with `std::vector`, you got valid empty value.

Comment: So it's merely a substitution from "out of bound access error" to "returning nothing"?